# Related to random variables algebra

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a doubt related to random variables. Consider that we have

$R_m^* = \underset{1\leq m \leq M}{\operatorname{argmax}} |h_m|^2$, ------(1)

where $|h_m|^2$ is a random variable. Further, since all the $|h_m|^2$ are independent and identically distributed (iid), so the CDF of $R_m^*$ can be written as

$F_{R_m}^*(x) = [F_{R_m}(x)]^M$ ----(2).

I had understood both eq.(1) and (2).

Now say I have the equation (3) as

$R_m^* = \underset{1\leq m \leq M}{\operatorname{argmin}} |h_m|^2$, ------(3)

My doubt is can I represent CDF of $F_{R_m}^*(x)$ of equation (3) in the similar way to equation (2) or will there be any change due to presence of $\text{argmin}$ as compared to $\text{argmax}$.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to subtract from $1$ a couple of times

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Can you please explain it in more detail....

Comment: What is $F_{R_m}$ in (2)?

Comment: It is the CDF of $R_m$.... and $F_{R_m}^*$ is the CDF of maximum (largest) of $R_m$.

Comment: and what is $R_m$?

Comment: $R_m$ is $m^{th}$ value of $|h_m|^2$..

Comment: Your notation is inconsistent. For example, $R^*$ should not depend on $m$. Also, do you mean $\max$ instead of $\operatorname{argmax}$?

Comment: Ok... Then in that case how to proceed...

Comment: The cdf in (2) is the cdf of $\max_{1\le m\le M} |h_m|^2$...

Comment: ok...but my doubt is how to write CDF of equation (3)

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to find - the cdf of $\min\ldots$ or $\operatorname{argmin} \ldots$ Try to fix the question first.

Comment: I want to find CDF of $\textbf{argmin}$

Comment: The cdf of an integer that gives the largest value of $|h_m|^2$ or the distribution of the corresponding $h_m$?

Comment: Ok.. My query is in case of $argmax$, the CDF has $M$ in power . So in case of $argmin$, the $M$ will it be in power or in division..

Comment: Well. According to your comments $R_m=[|h_1|^2,|h_2|^2,\ldots, |h_M|^2]_m$. In this case, $[F_{R_m}(x)]^M=\mathsf{P}(\max |h_m|^2\le x)$.

Comment: Exactly .... I got your point ...but this is for $\text{argmax}$. But how to write for $\text{argmin}$.

Comment: @paru My point was that (2) is for $\max$, not $\operatorname{argmax}$.

Comment: Ok...got the point perfectly.....now my query is : in case of $\textbf{min}$, will the (2) remain same or will there be any change....

Comment: $\mathsf{P}(\min |h_m|^2>x)=\prod_{m=1}^M \mathsf{P}(|h_m|^2>x)=(1-F_{R_m}(x))^M$.

Comment: Ok.. why did you changed the sign to greater than (>) in case of $\textbf{min}$